# What's the point in Stack Status if it (almost) always reports "All systems operational"?

Tags: discussion, stack-status

A while ago we had [Stack Status](https://www.stackstatus.net/) announced. The point of the site was to let keep us better apprised of problems on the site. Why then, is it almost always reporting "All systems operational" when they aren't operational?

Take the downtime that is occurring over on Main at the moment, right now, Stack Status is reporting *"All systems operational"* yet the user base knows this isn't true.

More odd, when the site did initially go down, an [incident](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/53ed5948-65c4-4e2e-9439-0c77c7592aa5) *was* raised and the sites showed as unavailable, however, that incident was seemingly deleted, and the status of the sites changed to "operational" while they were still down.

What I don't understand is, why implement a tool to keep the userbase better apprised if:

1. It isn't correct.
2. When it is correct, delete the incident(s) and make it incorrect

Stack Status currently says that there have been 2 incidents in the last 2 weeks, but based on my personal use, there has been an incident on *most* days (there was a probably with users getting blocked access via rate limiting yesterday for example, and I'm sure I got the "offline for maintenance" message earlier in the week).

During the time I have written this, the site has remained "offline" for the majority of the time, and there was a downtime before I started typing this.

Stack Status was a good idea, and it's a good tool if it is used correctly; why therefore isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it's deader than 'Dead' Jock McDead, again:(  'The service is unavailable.'

Comment: Well, there's at least there new [incident](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/8d533a56-bacb-48e3-baa5-8266d93f08c3) (though I dispute the time of said incident, as it was *not* there are 14:42 (which I assume is my local time)).

Comment: Now it shows "Outage". Maybe it just doesn't update as fast as you would like. I can also confirm that SO worked about ~10mins ago for me, so it can't be wrong for that long (although not reliable).

Comment: Stack isn't exactly super fast at responding to these things, but that might be down to the dev team already being minimal. I agree, though; as it currently stands, stackstatus is completely useless. There [are better platforms](https://discordstatus.com/) for tracking statuses. One thing that would make stackstatus useful is some automated systems. Not necessarily automatic incident declaration, but at least a ping graph, and consistent use of stackstatus when there's real maintenance would go a long way towards making it a bit more useful

Comment: Though personally, I just assume that if SO is down, it's being DDoSed, because for the past few months, that has been 100% correct. SE has never been good at transparency either, at least not during ongoing incidents. I'm not even asking for a lot, just an acknowledgement that the site is being DDoSed and measures are being taken to mitigate it is better than radio silence, either with no details but an acknowledgement that a thing happened that has been fixed, or [by not reporting anything about the downtime at all](https://www.stackstatus.net/history?start=2022-02-01&end=2022-04-30).

Comment: ... though for the sake of balance, they did at one point write a blog post about their DDoS mitigation, as well as parts of the adaption the attackers did, and their countermeasures, but that doesn't help when the transparency is needed right as The Thing:tm: happens. Don't get me wrong, the blog post (or MSE question, I forget) was still nice, but doesn't help much when new stuff happens

Comment: I assume you mean this annoucement, [Update on the ongoing DDoS attacks and blocking Tor exit nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/update-on-the-ongoing-ddos-attacks-and-blocking-tor-exit-nodes), @ZoestandswithUkraine . I agree, it was nice to get an update a the time, and gave us a reason for why the sites has been so flaky of late. Just frustrating that it's been radio silence since, as you note. It's a real motivation killer to be trying to answer a question to be greeted with errors.

Comment: @Larnu that's the one, yeah. Hard to tell if the attackers this time are the same as the previous attacks, but I guess that's fully irrelevant. I fully agree it's a motivation killer, especially when (seemingly random) instability is part of it. I hope they find a way to nail the attackers to the wall at some point

Comment: FWIW it now shows it's down. I should also note that, within the industry, very few status pages reflect problems in real-time. AWS, for instance, sometimes takes hours to show there's a problem, if at all.

Comment: Doesn't the error page already do a great job of telling you there's an error anyway?

Comment: Worth adding that [the incident](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/8d533a56-bacb-48e3-baa5-8266d93f08c3) that's been added since the creation of this post _does_ list "high load" as the culprit, which definitely leans towards DDOS, if not saying it explicitly.

Comment: @Machavity FWIW, it showed that the site is down within a few minutes of this post being made, which itself was within a few minutes of the incident happening. So the status page might not be real time, but it's really damn close to that.

Comment: I'm sick of this DDOS <expletive deleted>. Why can't people just use MSDOS like we used to?

Comment: I can't speak officially on behalf of the SRE team, but they are making efforts to make the automation between internal incident management and external visibility a lot more, well, automatic. In multiple recent incidents the automation did not work as defined/expected and so some manual intervention still has to take place. Until we get that automation completely sorted out, I think it's expected that our priority is going to be (a) get the site up (b) anything else.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can't remember the last time I checked stackstatus, I assumed it was hooked up because of the test message. Re: DDoS, a lot of us assume the downtime is malicious, because it's been happening a lot, and as a post linked earlier here backs up, there's a statement from SE that acknowledges that there have been proper, malicious attacks, and that they're highly adaptive. That doesn't guarantee downtime = DDoS, I'll give you that, but you lot give us absolutely no indication. The consistency and emerging nature of repeated downtime matches that of an attack

Comment: However, I find it incredibly hard to believe there's a huge amount of crawlers going haywire at the same time, several times per month, causing an accidental DDoS, and for the pool to magically refill in time for a new attack. A large-scale attack was reported to take down the site previously; if you claim a couple crawlers with a bad rate limit can do that, I have some concerns about the state of Stack's Q&A software. A bad crawler might take down a tiny server, but you lot operate at an enormous scale as-is. Blame assignment to non-malicious crawlers does NOT hold water at your scale

Comment: "I think that’s unfair." -- historically, not so much. "We try, we’re getting better" - which I've noticed when revisiting today, and quite honestly, that's all I want to see. "give us the benefit of the doubt" - the doubt has very much been cleared years ago. Transparency has historically not been a priority, and ironically, there's not a whole lot of transparency in you apparently wanting to be more transparent now. Outage reporting now being a focus is news to me, and something I wouldn't have noticed if this meta post and comment section hadn't appeared. Please keep the effort up

Comment: ""we have to balance making you aware there’s an issue with giving too many specifics" - "Our team is aware of a DDoS attack, and are trying to mitigate it" is itself transparent, but without actually helping in any way. There's a difference between transparency and "give us all the details about everything". "What are you going to do differently if you know an outage is malicious or a power cord trip" - there's a difference between a large-scale DDoS and the servers being down due to an accidental cable unplugging. If it's known to be an attack, at least personally, I back off to not add load

Comment: *"it showed that the site is down within a few minutes of this post being made, which itself was within a few minutes of the incident happening"* This isn't true, @MegaIng , Stack Status had a new, back dated, status created shortly after I made this post, but the site itself had been down, or very unstable, for at least 30 minutes when I made this post (the fact that the downtime was back dated to 13:42 UTC, which is 15 minutes before this post shows it was more than a "few minutes").

Comment: "some activity still catches weaknesses" - of course it does, it's a digital system. I'm globbing in the crawler statements made later for this bit; malicious or not, if a couple crawlers regularly stumble into weak endpoints, that once again brings the state of SE's software and protection into question. The site has been relatively stable for the past few years as well, barring intentional maintenance (and as far as I know, always announced in advance) that goes sideways. That happens, and that's fine. other weak spots also happen in any digital system.

Comment: "And my point is not to misdirect and mislead people into believing a malicious DDoS attack isn't one" - I never said it was. "It's more that it simply doesn't matter if it's malicious or accidental" - if stackstatus was something people could rely on, parts of the real traffic would be stopped if it being an attack was made clear. I have absolutely no clue by how much, but a lot of legitimate users spamming F5 for that thing they need now doesn't help either. Cutting out even a few can and does help with recovery, instead of accidentally turning real users into part of the problem

Comment: "My issue (and it is only a personal opinion) is simply with the word "attack" - it makes you sound like you want to (have to?) blame someone for doing something evil" - it's not about assigning blame, it's about trying not to be part of the problem, it's about determining whether or not I can expect to wait a few minutes, or wait a few hours. Some of the adaptive DDoS attacks have taken longer to recover from, and that's because your mitigation actually is different. A real attack prepared in advance to switch endpoints when one issue is fixed can and will result in a more complex fix, and

Comment: longer wait times for outage fixes. Making that clear through stackstatus (and to be abundantly clear, I'm aware you've said you're trying. This is a statement of consequences and impact, not a "you're failing to do so") can reduce traffic to aid in recovery, and massively improves the UX when it's clear that Stack isn't necessarily coming up in half a minute. That's where Discord excels compared to SO historically; as frustrating as downtime is, Discord often gives time estimates on complex issues, and always have included status updates on progress and recovery.

Comment: There's delay, sure, but discordstatus is a reliable source of Discord's status. Historically, stackstatus has not been reliable for Stack's status. _That_ is why I've status-reviewed the question. My intent was for Stack's incident reporting systems and routines to be revisited so stackstatus could be useful for end users, but you're apparently way ahead of us on getting to that point

Comment: "As for giving minute-by-minute updates on time to resolution" - it's not about minute resolution, it's about displaying progression. The time estimates aren't always accurate, though. Last time I saw them, they were in the form of "Next update at <time>", and I believe it was either half an hour or an hour between. It was a substantial outage. "I just don't agree that people will wait for stackstatus regardless of how much you trust it or not" - you're right, a lot won't. But it's still a source you lot (or rather, the social media team, assuming they're at work during an outage) can use

Comment: to engage with users. Retaining users rather than giving the perception that SO/SE is regularly down for what users perceive as no reason what so ever should be in your interest.

Comment: "I never said a couple of crawlers could (or did!) take the site down" -- you wrote "Sometimes this type of activity can be triggered by crawlers", which reads as "this is a thing that actually has and does happen". Interpreting that as a general statement was indeed a bit extreme on my side, but your statement does open for various interpretations, including that one. In fact, in context, I personally interpreted all your examples as being things that has happened, or does happen occasionally. My comments on that were not intended to be "they do", but "if they do". I'm happy it isn't the case

Comment: Interpreting that as a couple scrapers is somewhat thin, I'll give you that. It's a semi-arbitrary number on the grounds that there aren't a whole lot of large-scale scrapers (search engines, particularly). The rest are mostly unofficial scrapers that should be using the API instead, and SO has automatic IP ban-based rate limits for similar activity.

Answer (score 8):

Apologies for the late response, lifted from the larger [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381161/recent-site-instability-major-outages-july-august-2022):

> Now that we have an automated status page, we are examining how we can improve the process so that it is updated sooner. Other improvements revolve around additions to the status page itself and how information is displayed. To be clear, the status page reflects that a human is working on the issue, not whether our monitoring system has detected issues. We are working to improve internal processes related to communication, standardizing processes to be more consistent, and clarifying what events trigger communication.